# how to check given datetime has offset in python

Tags: python, django

i have this three datetime from the user input with offset like below

`2019-04-02 11:11:31.552611+00` and

`2019-06-20 12:48:56.862291+05:30` and

`2019-06-20 12:48:56.862291+00:00`

which is saved in my Django local database but now i have to check this `datetime` has offset other than `+00:00`

so how to check?

Comment: forms and all not required to check whether it(input datetime) has offset other than +00:00, just python logic function is enough

Comment: answer is parser.parse('2019-06-20 12:48:56.862291+00:00').utcoffset().total_seconds() is == 0.0 then it is offset is +00

Answer (score 0):

You may want to include more information about your situation since it seems like a weird situation to me. Typically datetimes are stored in UTC in Django, then converted back to the requesting user's timezone.

But to answer your immediate question:

```
def has_utc_offset(value):
    offset = value.utcoffset()
    if offset is None:
        return None
    return offset.total_seconds() == 0.0
```

Here are the docs: https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.utcoffset

Comment: while accepting input from django drf we need to validate like there are sending in utc format or not from angular l

Comment: parser.parse('2019-06-20 12:48:56.862291+00:00').utcoffset() is None and parser.parse('2019-06-20 12:48:56.862291+05:00').utcoffset() is None both are giving false, required output shoulbe first false and second is true

Comment: The docs require the tzinfo to be set for it to not return None. You need to parse out the tzinfo in the input to make use of this. You should look into a different datetime parser. Perhaps `dateutil`?

Comment: so how to check given input has offset other than +00:00

Answer (score 0):

using total second i partially solved my problem

```
    if parser.parse('2019-06-20 12:48:56.862291+00:00').utcoffset().total_seconds() is == 0.0:
        return True # it has 00 offset
    else:
        return False # it has other format
```